# Foods that "insult" the body

Tags: word-usage, north-american-english, medical

How common is the word ***insult*** in the sense "[cause] bodily injury/trauma" in modern day English?

Is it chiefly medical speak, or has it spread into general print that even the layperson knows what it means?

**insult**

> :  injury to the body or one of its parts; also :  something that causes or has a potential for causing such insult : *pollution and other environmental insults*
>
> :  injury to the body or one of its parts : *repeated acute vascular insults*; *any insult to the constitution of a patient suffering from active tuberculosis*—Journal of the American Medical Association

[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insult)

> *n.* *NAm:* *Med:* blessure; lésion (du corps)
>
> *v.* *NAm:* *Med:* ***foods that insult the body***, nourriture qui nuit à la santé (*lit.* foods that ruin health)
>
> *insults the body* [Google Search](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&site=&source=hp&q=%22see+synonyms+for+breach%22&oq=%22see+synonyms+for+breach%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...3591.19904.0.20488.26.26.0.0.0.0.344.5162.0j9j13j1.23.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..10.16.3699.0.54cP_DA_Pi8#q=%22insults+the+body%22)
>
> *insult the body* [Google Search](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&site=&source=hp&q=%22see+synonyms+for+breach%22&oq=%22see+synonyms+for+breach%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...3591.19904.0.20488.26.26.0.0.0.0.344.5162.0j9j13j1.23.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..10.16.3699.0.54cP_DA_Pi8#q=%22insult+the+body%22)

Source: Harrap's New Shorter French and English Dictionary, Ed. 1985

> In medical and scientific jargon, often means "something that disturbs normal functions; a trauma"

Source: Garner's Modern American Usage, Third Edition - Oxford University Press (2009)

Comment: "Foods that insult the body", in the US, would be pseudo-medical-speak, used by people pushing some sort of diet protocol.

Comment: It's a figurative usage of the sense *To make an attack or assault*, which OED says is now ***obsolete*** as a "literal" usage. Personally, I think it's pretty quaint/dated even figuratively.

Comment: It's a metaphor. It's not terribly common. It sounds a little 'too much' to me. It's understandable as is outside of medicine, but like the author is trying a little too hard.

Comment: Let's suppose I am having a double Big Mac after twisting my ankle, am I adding insult to injury? :P

Comment: "foods that insult the body" sounds like language that is used in rather dodgy ads on the internet to try to sell people snake oil. But the meaning would be clear to everybody.

Comment: You might say that a certain food *"doesn't agree with you"* - this is still quite a common usage. I suppose that an insult is an extreme sign of disagreement. It would be interesting to learn which term came first.

Comment: It is understandable to laypeople, but for me evokes a correlation with "an insult to God" in the sense of treating the body as a temple.

Comment: be careful of adding insult to injury! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak for the medical field, but in popular literature, such a phrase would be unusual.

I doubt an average reader without any medical experience would have any trouble discerning the meaning, but the usage would be markedly more poetic than prosaic.